# Temporal operations with a layout manager? Best design?

Tags: java, image, swing, layout, layout-manager

I'm working on a kind of image gallery in Swing (a view of a jscrollpane basically), but I'm a bit stuck.

I have modified MigLayout so it can give me some extra functionality that I need.

I have some parts of my logic, that in order to take a decision I have to lay out my view under some specific constraints to see how it would look like, such as the width at 100%, the number of columns, the biggest component in a column under a specific zoom level, etc.

But, I don't want to see my components flickering while I'm doing these "tests". So what I'm doing is creating a second orphan JPanel with a copy of my components, so I can do these "tests" without affecting my final and effective view. But this solution sounds to me a bit botched and a bit sluggish. I could also do something like disabling the "setBounds" while I do these tests, but it is not nice either.

I know the best thing would be not to do these tests, but that sounds easier to say than to do. And anyway I'm not convince about that either.

Have you ever find yourself on this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that shows your problem.

Answer (score 2):

No need to layout first. `LayoutManager` has methods to calculate the size first

```
Dimension preferredLayoutSize(Container parent);

/**
 * Calculates the minimum size dimensions for the specified
 * container, given the components it contains.
 * @param parent the component to be laid out
 * @see #preferredLayoutSize
 */
Dimension minimumLayoutSize(Container parent);

/**
 * Lays out the specified container.
 * @param parent the container to be laid out
 */
void layoutContainer(Container parent);
```

So I would recomment to write let's say `calculatePreferrence()` method where you use minimum/maximum/preferred sizes of container's children to figure out desired size and return it in the preferredLayoutSize (and minimumLayoutSize). Then just use the calculations.

Comment: I know that.....
but that is true as long as you don't need to check sizes with a different set of constraints on components and sizes.